# How to use my Spatio-Temporal Data to Make a Prediction?

Tags: machine-learning, regression, interpolation, geospatial, temporal

I have a Dataset in the form of:

Timestamp (Daily Interval)

Latitude

Longtitude

Target Value (y).

So I want to train a model with these data and perform an interpolation. So I use all of the Data in the Training Process and during the Testing Process the inputs will be **x = [timestamp, lat, lon]** with the prediction being a Target Value. So the spatial and temporal aspects are really important.

My Question is what model to use and how to handle my data?
One very simple but not sophisticated solution I tried was to use a **KNN Regressor**, so given the time,lat,lon it finds the nearest neighbors and gives the Target Value.
Any Ideas how I should handle the ***spatio-temporal data***?

Thank you

Comment: This does not seem to be a question about programming, Otherwise please be more focused on your algorithm and provide it in a source-code form as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is better suited for Data Science community:
 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

There are many ways to approach this problem, depending on what kind of data this represents and what kind of predictions you want to make. A good discussion of kind of predictions could be found in a recent Kaggle competition, see Notebooks and Discussions there:

https://www.kaggle.com/c/bigquery-geotab-intersection-congestion/overview

That competition used [BigQueryML](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/bigqueryml-intro) - as the very simplest approach you can feed the input data to BigQueryML K-Means model, and get predictions. Note that BigQueryML supports Geography type, so you should feed it Geography (using `ST_GeogPoint(longitude, latitude)`) - it will give you better results than feeding lat/lon as independent variables without spatial semantics.